# Use next-intl outside of a react component

Tags: next.js, internationalization, translation

Is there any way to use `next-intl` outside of a react component?

For now I get `t` by calling the hook `useTranslations`, and then pass its instance to my function:

```js
function formatFoo(t, foo) {
    if ....
        t('bar');
}

export default function MyComponent() { 
    const t = useTranslations();
    return <div>{formatFoo(t, "bar")}</div>
}
```

I wish I could just import `t` from `next-intl` as `i18next` permits for example.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone else that needs to get messages in async functions, here you go

```
let messages = {};

export const getTranslation = async (
  namespace,
  key,
) => {
  // this should be up to you, maybe from app state or from cookies
  const locale = getLocale() ?? "en";
  messages =
    Object.keys(messages).length == 0
        (await import(`../messages/${locale}.json`)).default
      : messages;

  const t = createTranslator({ locale, messages, namespace });
  return t(key);
};
```

source https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/usage/core-library

Answer (score 1):

Is there an issue with calling `formatFoo` directly in the component body and using `t` from the outside closure?

```
export default function MyComponent() { 
  const t = useTranslations();

  function formatFoo(foo) {
    if ....
      return t('bar');
  }

  return <div>{formatFoo('bar')}</div>
}
```

`next-intl` only offers an API to use translations from within React components.

This may seem like an unnecessary limitation, but this is intentional and aims to encourage the use of proven patterns that avoid potential issues like your formatted messages becoming out of sync with app state.

I've written a blog post that discusses the background of this design decision: [How (not) to use translations outside of React components](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/blog/translations-outside-of-react-components).

Note: I'm the maintainer of next-intl.

Comment: Hi @amann, thanks for your answer. In my case I have several `formatFoo` grouped in a `formatter.service.ts`. Passing `t` to each of these functions was a pain, so I end-up using `i18next` which allows me to use my translations in `ts` files.

Comment: Sounds fine, just make sure the functions are called on re-render to make sure the rendered translation is in sync with app state! :)